# Why 'git diff' returns only file path without content?

Tags: git

If I run 'git diff' on my repo it gives:

```html
$ git diff
diff --git a/chapterOne.txt b/chapterOne.txt
index 3608209..1e48a32 100644
Binary files a/chapterOne.txt and b/chapterOne.txt differ
```

why it show only path? It should returns the changes in my files.

Comment: Because it believes these files are binary, and doesn't want to print non-printable junk

Comment: Probably UTF-8 (or some other) encoding on the text file?

Comment: @eftshift0 : did you mean UTF-16 ? iirc, git simply checks if it sees a `\0` byte at the beginning (first few kilobytes) of a file

Comment: You got that one right, @LeGEC. UTF-16 (or some other) :-)